Перестали приходить пуш-уведомления с Авито
Помогите пожалуйста, техподдержка Авито помочь не смогла: мне перестали приходить пуш-уведомления с Авито. Раньше приходили, и вдруг не знаю после чего перестали. Может после обновления Windows, может после обновления браузера, а может на Авито что-то испортилось. Или не знаю что еще может быть
Особенно неприятно отсутствие пушей о новых сообщениях в мессенджере. Раньше благодаря им я мог отвечать на сообщения сразу, теперь могу только когда придет уведомления о новом сообщении на эл.почту, а это происходит только минут через пятнадцать
Техподдержка наверно помочь не смогла потому, что у меня довольно редкая конфигурация - у меня нет смарфона, сайт Авито я использую исключительно с обычного компьютера. На нем Windows 7 и Яндекс-браузер. По вопросу отсутствия пушей я уже писал и в техподдержку Авито, и в техподдержку Яндекса. Пока помочь не смогли. Может у вас найдутся идеи? Из-за чего могут не приходить пуш-уведомления? как заставить их приходить
По запросам техподдержки уже пробовал заставить следующим образом:

Выходить из своего профиля на Авито и зайти заново. Не помогает
Ставить Яндекс-браузер на новый компьютер с Windows Server 2008R2 и получать там уведомления с Авито. Тоже не приходят
Зайти на Авито в другой аккаунт (у меня там их два) и там получать пуш-уведомления. Не приходят тоже
Добавить в Яндекс-браузере новый профиль и попробовать получать пуш-уведомления там. Тоже не приходят
Тестировать получение пушей на сайте https://simple-push-demo.vercel.app/ Оттуда приходят железно, стопроцентно
Тестировать приходят ли уведомления в любом другом браузере — Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox или Google Chrome. Результаты такие:


Google Chrome больше не работает на Windows 7, вот уже несколько лет
Internet Explorer не умеет отображать пуш-уведомления
От Microsoft Edge удалось добиться отображения пуш-уведомлений только с сайта mail.yandex.ru только после ручного добавления mail.yandex.ru в разрешения уведомлений. С сайтов e.mail.ru и mail.rambler.ru добиться отображения пуш-уведомлений не удалось, несмотря даже на ручное добавление этих сайтов в разрешения уведомлений
От Firefox не удалось добиться отображения пуш-уведомлений ни с одного из сайтов mail.yandex.ru, e.mail.ru, mail.rambler.ru. Причем вручную добавить сайты в разрешения уведомлений в Firefox нельзя - нету в нем такой возможности в настройках (сайты добавляет в разрешения только при положительном ответе пользователя на запрос сайта на показ уведомлений, а таковых запросов пользователю почему-то не поступает)

Какие будут еще идеи?

Кто поставил -1 - скажите пожалуйста, за что??

Чем обусловлено использование устаревшего и неподдерживаемого ПО?

Тем что оно работает быстрее, чем Windows 10 или 11. Кроме того, под 11 вообще придется покупать новый компьютер. А 10 работает заметно медленнее чем Windows 7. Да и нет в нем ничего нового, что могло бы мне понадобиться. Поэтому нет смысла осваивать новый Windows. Да и проблема неприхода пушей на Windows 10 имеется точно такая же, как на Windows 7 - протестировал в виртуальной машине VirtualBox

Кроме того, Windows 7 - оно поддерживаемое. Последнее обновление было от 10.09.2024

Прошло всего полтора месяца (с 16 сентября) с момента моего первого письма в техподдержку Авито по этому поводу, и вот представьте себе - вчера проблема решена! Получил письмо из техподдержки: «вы обращались в службу поддержки: в браузере не приходили уведомления. Мы все починили. Если проблема повторится, пожалуйста, напишите нам». Проверил - действительно заработало, то есть стали приходить пуш-уведомления с Авито о новых сообщениях в мессенджере (ну и все остальные виды пушей наверно тоже).
Таким образом, все танцы с бубном были ни к чему. Проблема была на Авито, и единственно правильным ответом было «не слезать с техподдержки», что я и делал: я регулярно напоминал им, что проблема всё еще не решена. И это помогло. Техподдержке конечно зачот
